# Using UID to pass transaction data to GA in measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, measurement-protocol

We have a Lead generation website, where conversion action is a form submit. A percentage of these leads get enrolled offline.

We plan to use measurement protocol to tie-back this revenue to google analytics.

The set-up is as follows:

1. Enable User-ID feature in Google Analytics
2. Sending the Unique ID generated by our CRM software as the User-ID in google analytics.
3. When one of the lead converts offline, we pass that information back to GA - and the associated UID shows the final conversion as well.

How do we proceed with step 3 and tie-back the revenue to the User-ID from transactions that happened offline?

As per explanation given in measurement protocol, only CID can be used to send the transaction values to GA.

Is it possible to do it using UID only?

Thanks

Comment: If you have session unification enabled the transaction should be attributed to the correct user, even if you create a new cid. However the transaction will be attributed to a new session (so you might lose the marketing channel information fpr the transaction).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send a UserID via the measurement protocol please see the following page for details:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uid

In essence you add &uid=USER_ID to your request URL

However you must also supply a ClientId, the usual approach would be to store the ClientID of the user against the user record in your database when they submit the form online, which you can then later use to reattach to the request you send via the measurement protocol.

To get the clientId from the form is simple

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#getting_the_client_id_from_the_cookie